# How to check if a list is equal to another lists element(s) without knowing the length of the second list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

```
N = int(input("Write a number between 3 and 10 to the power of 18: "))
P = int(input("How many questions did Partick get right: "))

a,b = [],[]
for i in range(P):
    Pi = int(input("Write the indexes of the questions: "))
    a.append(Pi)
F = int(input("How many questions did Fabijan get right: "))
for i in range(F):
    Fi = int(input("Write the indexes of the questions: "))
    b.append(Fi)
g = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
```

And here i hit a roadblock. I want to compare all the elements of list `a` with all the elements of list `b`. To be clearer i want to compare all of the elements of list `a` with each element of list `b` without knowing the exact length of list `b`.

Comment: Translate your prompts into English, it'll help you get answers. Add some example input and expected output.

Comment: It'd help if you could be more specific. Does the order of elements matter? How are you going to consider duplicate elements? There are many details left unanswered.

Comment: Provide sample inputs and what your desired output would look like based on those inputs, to make a [mcve]

Comment: So basically what i want to do is compare a[i] with b[0] and then b[1] and so on but the problem is i dont know the exact length of b

Comment: Can you give a concrete example what `a` and `b` should look like after they are populated, and what result you want from such a comparison?

Comment: If nothing else, you can always *get* the length of `b` with `len(b)`.

Comment: This is not the entire question this is just sample code and i don't really care if i finish the question i just want to know how can i do this.

Comment: I do not want to do anything with a or b i just want to make an `if` statement and if it is True i want to add 1 to `g`

Comment: If *what* is true? What comparison do you want to make? There are lots of possibilities: `a[0] == b[0]`, `a[0] < b[0]`, `a[3] > b[2]`, etc. What code would you write if you *did* know the length to `b`?

Comment: for example `if a[i] != b[0]` and then with b[1] and b [2] and so on but i don't know the length of b

Comment: Do you care if an elemnt may occur more than once in `b`? If not, use `a[i] in b` (there is a better way doing that in a loop). (Still awaiting those examples, though.)

Comment: No i do not care if that happens, so basically in that for loop up above i want to write `if a[i] != b[0]` and then b[1] and so on but i don't know how many times to do that since i don't know the length of b

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to count ***each*** occurrence of `a[i]` in `b`, or just count once if it occurs?

If it's the latter, then your solution is available on the other answer and comments.

For the sake of completeness, I'll answer assuming you meant the former question.

---

Iterate over `a`, and then over `b`, and count every time the elements match between each other.

```py
g = 0
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i == j:
            g += 1
```

Also, this can be way simplified using [`list.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```py
g = sum(b.count(i) for i in a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "in". Something like this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in b:
```

Comment: Thank you both this is so obvious.I am embarrassed